# Why was this question about usage of twofold/threefold deleted

Tags: discussion

Why was this question about [usage of twofold/threefold](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/71654/252) deleted?

No explanation is given. I find it hard to imagine this one is General Reference, when I compare it to countless other really trivial questions that *don't* get deleted.

Comment: It could be related to the "voting irregularities" that user was involved with maybe? It was mod deleted

Comment: @simchona: You're absolutely right! I see the OP's account has been suspended. Not sure of the etiquette here, but I've just [re-posted it myself](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/72089/the-problem-is-twofold/72090#72090) (along with my own answer! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This seems to be exactly the kind of question we do want. It asks about grammar and the answers involve discussions of semantics, usage, and definitions.

Answer (score 8):

The question was plagiarized from another online forum. Based on this user's previous behavior, deletion was the appropriate course of action. The question itself is not necessarily close-worthy, which is why I didn't close it before deleting.

Comment: Is there a difference between "closed and deleted" and just "deleted"?

Comment: @MarkBeadles Closing usually provides an explanation for why something was eventually deleted, and serves as a barrier if the question were to be undeleted if the question should remain closed even though it was undeleted.

Comment: Aha! That explanation makes sense, I've always wondered about that, thanks.

Comment: Um, plagiarized? It's just a short question, how can that be plagiarized? So it was copied. Is that bad? As long as we can come up with interesting answers, is it a problem? I realize that this user is problematic, but still, if you look at the question itself... **[edit:]** Oh, I see FF has reposted it under his own name.